# .htaccess redirect conflict wordpress /wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I will try to be the most specific as I can when I request help in solving this problem, though I don't have much knowledge about the configuration files used by Wordpress here!

The main folder in the website have this code in .htaccess as my objective was to remove .html from pages

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index.html\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I've also installed wordpress to a /blog folder only inside the main folder. Now I can't access /wp-admin/ (*/blog/wp-admin/), and am receiving an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How might I correct this?

Comment: Default wordpress .htaccess code are you removed

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess content with this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]
```